# BinaryFormatter serialization/deserialization alternative in Android

Tags: android, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I have a class serialized in C# using BinaryFormatter serialize method. Is there any way i can de-serialize it in android application. I mean is there any alternatives of BinaryFormatter in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after doing some research.

In order to de-serialize objects in android (java) which were serialized in .Net, we have to serialize our class in .Net using custom serialization, i mean by using primitive datatypes instead of using built in .Net serializers. And then android application de-serialize in exact same order using primitive data types.

To summarize we need to write primitive data types on stream in some order and in android read from stream the same primitive data types in exact same order they were written in .Net.
XML can also be used for serializing and de-serializing

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi Omar, is there any way to serialize the object in c# and read it back in android(java)?

Comment: Hi, As I mentioned in answer, you have to use custom serialization instead of using built in .Net serializer. By custom serialization I mean you would have to write your object using Writter methods like writer.writeInt(intVariable) and read in android reader.readInt() in same order.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the following URL regarding java seralization against .NET serialization

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e474a3yk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Deepak, I tried this to read the file but this always gives me a java.io.StreamCorruptedException exception.